# No scrollbar in <object>

Tags: html, css, object

For security reasons I was looking at *object* instead of *iframe* for diplaying a html page on my site but I could not get rid of this nasty scrollbar that comes with it.

So I fiddle around with some css like:

```
overflow: hidden; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;
```

but that did not work in IE so I came up with the following:

```
min-height: 408px;
min-width: 1024px;
```

This got rid of the scrollbar.

Question is:

Am I doing this the right way or is this a "hack" which can better be avoided?

Here some code

**HTML**

```
<object type="text/html" data="cloudtag.html" class="object_1" name="content"></object>
```

**CSS**

```
.object_1 {
    min-height: 408px;
    min-width:1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : transparent;
}
```

Comment: What "security reasons" might these be?

Comment: Yes, what 'security reasons'?

Comment: Use Google. some hacker can replace the loaded page in your Iframe with another. https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/blog/protect-your-website-from-embedded-content-iframe-security

Comment: Only if you let them.

Comment: Let's move away from the "security" issue. The question is Am I doing this the right way or is this a "hack" which can better be avoided?

I spend some hours looking for a solution on the scrollbar in objects but could not find anything.

Comment: use iframe and google how to get rid of scrollbars. if you want to use a "secure" version of iframe, use ajax call to your own server and/or use the php function file_get_contents. so nobody can hack around the url - if you are afraid about that.